# Timediff calucate where query

Tags: php, mysql, database, time

i have an query where i calculate the worked time for each user.

```
$sql = "
SELECT actief
     , userid
     , DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%x - %V')
     , username
     , min_urenperweek
     , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(tijd_tot) - TIME_TO_SEC(tijd_van))) timediff
  FROM " . TBL_URENREGISTRATIE . " ur
  JOIN " . TBL_CMS_USERS . " us 
    ON us.userid = ur.userid
 GROUP 
    BY YEARWEEK(datum)
     , userid 
 ORDER 
    BY us.username ASC
    " ;
```

what i want is : if the `min_urenperweek` lets say its 40hours and the `timediff` is more then 40hours, I don't want it to show it if it's less then 40 then i want to show it

I tried `Where min_urenperweek <= timediff` but it doesn't work

Comment: You could use HAVING, which comes after the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Do you maybe have an example how i can use that?

Comment: You might want to give DATE_FORMAT an alias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should have the same fields in the `GROUP BY` clause than those in your `SELECT` clause which are not aggregate functions.
2. You can't specify an alias from your `SELECT` clause in in your `WHERE` clause.
3. If you want to filter on the results of your aggregates, you can't do that in the `WHERE` clause, the `HAVING` clause exists for that purpose

Try something like this

```
$sql = "
SELECT actief
     , userid
     , DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%x - %V')
     , username
     , min_urenperweek
     , SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(tijd_tot) - TIME_TO_SEC(tijd_van))) timediff
  FROM " . TBL_URENREGISTRATIE . " ur
  JOIN " . TBL_CMS_USERS . " us 
    ON us.userid = ur.userid
 GROUP 
    BY actief
     , userid 
     , DATE_FORMAT(datum, '%x - %V')
     , username
     , min_urenperweek   
 HAVING min_urenperweek <= timediff
 ORDER 
    BY us.username ASC
    " ;
```

Comment: Graag gedaan ;-)